# how big technosphere matrices can be in brightway2

Tags: python-3.x, brightway

How big technosphere matrices can be in Brightway2 and still be invertible? From what I understood [here](https://chris.mutel.org/even-faster-lca.html) Brightway uses a wrapper to the Pardiso library to speed up matrix inversion. Compared with standard scipy libraries Pardiso is indeed much faster. But when I tested it I run into memory problems for matrices larger than 10000 rows. To invert the matrix I need to define a numpy array, which cannot be bigger than 1000000 rows on my laptop.

```
from pypardiso import spsolve
import numpy as np
ar=csc_matrix(np.eye(10000))
%time spsolve(ar,np.eye(10000))
```

Is it here the limit, or I can get around the use of numpy arrays?

(PS: I tested with standard scipy solvers and I can invert sparse matrices of 10^5 rows but its quite slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that Adrian Haas worked with a sparse matrix with more than 100 000 rows/columns. The only limit should be the memory in your machine, not in the software itself.

You can create the inverse column by column in a reasonable time, and get the benefit of much better numerical stability and the speed of pardiso:

```
In [1]: from brightway2 import *

In [2]: import pyprind

In [3]: from time import time

In [4]: db = Database("ecoinvent 3.5 cutoff")

In [5]: def invert(database):
   ...:    lca = LCA({database.random(): 1})
   ...:    lca.lci()
   ...:    for act in pyprind.prog_bar(database):
   ...:        lca.redo_lci({act: 1})
   ...:

In [6]: start = time(); invert(db); print(time() - start)
0%                          100%
[##############################] | ETA: 00:00:00
Total time elapsed: 00:03:21
202.16850423812866
```

However, in my experience it is very rare that someone actually needs the inverse of the technosphere.

Comment: True, calculating the supply array should be enough to do the inventory. I've just read in the documentation that for numerical analyst matrix inversion is a sin !

Comment: I made some quick tests with spsolve (Pardiso) and I can solve (very simple) systems with 10^8 equations relatively fast before running into memory problems.